# Not Accessing object using dropdown menus, ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

**Please find code sample below link for more details**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-with-menu

I have created a dropdown menu inside table tr, I want to call some function over dropdown menus, as per expectations, each click on row should transfer rendered object through function parameter, but its always transferring the first element.

Comment: So... you're giving us a link to some code. And?

Comment: my mistake!!   typing mistakes in title

Comment: @JeremyThille is it clear to understand now ?

Comment: Yes, much better, thanks. I understand why you are puzzled, because I am too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a conflict. You are loading jQuery in an Angular Project, because you are using Bootstrap, which depends on jQuery.

I deleted bootstrap and jQuery from your project and now it works, so it's a conflict between them.

Now I get this in the console :

```
> edit {text: "some text 3"}         preview-e6e32bdb6d8102b4a83ab.js:1      
> edit {text: "some text 4"}         preview-e6e32bdb6d8102b4a83ab.js:1
```

In general, it is a very bad idea to load and use jQuery in an Angular project, this can only lead to this kind of conflicts.

If you want to use Bootstrap in your angular project, use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).